# sed - remove unmatched "}", ")" or ']" (only for the line in question)

Tags: sed, ruby, rspec

I have a file with a lot of lines.

Some of the lines end in unmatched braces, i.e. "`}`"

This is only true for lines that contain `".to"`

How can I remove the unmatched braces with sed for ALL lines that contain a string ("`.to`") but don't have another string ("`{`") anywhere in the line (before or after the `.to`) but do end in "`}`"?

Something like `sed -i '/\.to/s/[[:space:]]*\}//' file`

but that would be for ALL lines that contain a string ("`.to`") and end in a "`}`"

I want it for lines that don't have a brace/bracket, e.g. `{` before the `}`

I do not need to worry about multi-line braces for this.  Limiting to lines that match a search ('.to' in this case) helps prevent that.

e.g.

```
  expect(:size).to eq 2 }
  expect(:first).to be_persisted }
  expect("first.number_field").to eq 10 }
  expect(:last).to be_persisted }
  expect("last.number_field").to eq 10 }
  this remains unchanged }
  this {remains} unchanged }
  this {
     is ok }

=>

  expect(:size).to eq 2
  expect(:first).to be_persisted
  expect("first.number_field").to eq 10
  expect(:last).to be_persisted
  expect("last.number_field").to eq 10
  this remains unchanged }
  this {remains} unchanged }
  this {
     is ok }
```

Comment: paste some sample, for testing..

Comment: Added some test examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply

```
sed -i 's@^\([^{]\+\)\(\.to[^{]\+\)}\s*$@\1\2@' your_file
```

With Perl (for better readability):

```
perl -pi -e 's@ 
                ^                  # start of line
                  ( [^{]+ )        # at least one non-{ character (save in $1)
                  (\.to [^{]+ )    # .to and at least one non-{ (save in $2)
                  }                # that pesky }
                  \s*              # optional white space
                $                  # end of line
              @$1$2@x' your_file
```

Answer (score 3):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and [look-around advanced regex](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) :

```
perl -lpe 's/((?<!\{).*?\.to.*)}\s*$/$1/' file
```

and with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '!/{/ && /\.to.*}/{sub(/\}/, "", $NF)}1' file
```

Comment: +1  thanks.  Would like to know about non-perl options too :)

Comment: Added awk solution